# Properly use Background Worker in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

i'm stuck in using properly the background worker, the app needs to communicate with the database, so it takes a bit longer and the UI freezes for a while, i need to create a function that does the database things and wait until the work is finished, for this time, i want to display a kind of window that inform the user about the app state (Loading, busy, Downloading).

**My code**

i didn't write any code yet, but here're what i need:

```
//instructions
InitializeComponent();

//do this in background and wait until it finnishes
GetEntitiesFromDatabase();

entitiesListView.ItemSource = someList; (GetEntitiesFromDatabase will initialize this list)
//....
```

How can i proceed, i know that this question might be already asked in the forum but i'm desperate by searching for an answer, if this can be done other way please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read documentation of `BackgroundWorker` or newer technologies such as `Task, async/await` to do long running operations asynchronously?

Comment: "I didn't write any code yet" -- IMHO, you should before you post a question. You should at least _try_ to come up with something that works before you look for other people to fix your problem for you. :p

Comment: hi @HamletHakobyan, i've heard about the assync/await thing, can you link good topics about it ?

Comment: Dear @PeterDuniho , i was trying different "non official" things but nothing used to work

Comment: If used properly, BackgroundWorker should "just work". It has events to subscribe to, such as one to do work, another to handle notifications to the caller, and a third to notify of completion. The notification events are raised by BackgroundWorker on the caller's thread. This works well in Forms, and should work just as well in WPF even though the event loop/dispatcher model is slightly different. So, implement something with BackgroundWorker and see how it goes.

Comment: @PeterDuniho i did, and used the waitone method to wait for work to be done, but it's not working.

Comment: Here is bunch of articles. https://www.google.com/search?q=Task%2C+async%2Fawait&oq=Task%2C+async%2Fawait&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @User1: you should not need to use WaitOne() when using BackgroundWorker. That's what it's completion event is for. Note that if you don't need notification of status during the work, using async/await with a Task is just as easy. Even if you do need notification, async/await with a Task plus using Dispatcher.Invoke/BeginInvoke explicitly for notifications (per BradlyDotNET's answer) is relatively easy too. If you tried something but couldn't get it to work, post a code example of that so people can help you get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to directly manipulate the UI like that, you need to use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` when you aren't on the UI thread (read, in the `BackgroundWorker`).

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
{
   entitiesListView.ItemSource = someList;
}), null);
```

You could also **bind** that items source to your view model (a much better idea) and the framework will marshal the change to the bound property for you.

Basically, either use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` or switch to MVVM (which WPF was meant to use anyways).

Comment: thanks for your answer, i user dispatcher.beginInvoke, but it doesn't work, not sure about your syntax tho : 

`ProductsListView.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                if(allProducts != null)
                    ProductsListView.ItemsSource = allProducts;
            }));`
i used this one, but the dispatcher doesn't update the listview item source

Comment: @User1 As long as you didn't get a cross-thread exception; it actually did. Check your variables to see what it is setting to. I fixed the syntax, thanks for noting the mistake.